# Does pre-assignment before conditions optimize memory for Collections in Java?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I've searched for my particular question but haven't found exact answer so far. 
Actually I am looking for simple answer.

Let's say we have a collection and we don't assign it in advance and use it twice. Once for condition statement and once inside the condition.

```
    if(!foo.getBooList().isEmpty()){
        for(Boo boo : foo.getBooList()){
             //...
        }
     }
```

And the second way of doing above is,

```
List<Boo> booList = foo.getBooList();

    if(!booList.isEmpty()){
        for(Boo boo : booList){
        //..
        }
    }
```

Also I know in terms of patterns 2nd one is better but I'm focused on behavior of jvm about memory in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There won't be any difference. But for the sake of simplicity and readability, just remove your if condition, which is useless. You can iterate on an empty collection. The loop will just never execute. So the `if` is redundant.

Comment: Right, thank you. But I want to mention that; not only collections but also calling get() methods on different objects every time does not make difference right? Or we need to call get() once and assign it to corresponding object reference then use that reference?

Comment: It depends on what get() does. If it just returns a field (as getters usually do), then it doesn't make any difference. If it involves a computation that ends up returning something, then the computation will be done every time you invoke the method. But anyway, you should strive for readability, instead of focusing on performance. Calling a traditional getter consumes 0 memory and 0 CPU. That's not what will cause performance issues.

Comment: So clear answer thank you. I was talking about traditional getters. But then I also realized a case from your comment; let's say we have a relation of two entities and we're lazy initializing the child entity. As we know when we call get() for that child it will query and initialize the child. In that case I must be careful how many time I'm using get() method right?

Comment: No. First, calling the getter is not what is initializing the collection. The getter just returns a reference to the collection, initialized or not. What initializes the lazy collection is a call to any of its method (size(), isEmpty(), iterator(), whatever). And of course, only the first call to a method initializes the collection. Once it's initialized, it's initialized. It won't reinitialize every time you call a method.

Comment: I got it very clear! Thank you for your excellent answers.

Comment: As said by @JBNizet, it depends on what `getBooList()` does. Since looking at method invocations won’t tell you, I consider declaring a local variable more readable, as it will tell the reader *immediately*, that this is the same collection. Though, here, it is even more readable to write just `for(Boo boo : foo.getBooList()){ ... }` and omit the superfluous `if` statement, as a loop over a collection does already nothing when the collection is empty.